# Bootstrap dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am in need of help with Bootstrap 4.4.1. I have two consecutive dropdown links+menus, properly aria-labelled with different names. However the second dropdown menu displays the menu associated with the previous link, not its own, even tho the mappings are correct.

The code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" 
href="#" title="Actions" 
role="button" 
id="dropdownActionMenu13"
data-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-haspopup="true" 
aria-expanded="false">actions</a>&nbsp;
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionMenu13">
<a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-category/action/13/hello_world">Hello World</a>
</div>

<a class="dropdown-toggle" 
href="#" title="Related" 
role="button" 
id="dropdownActionGoTo13"
data-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-haspopup="true" 
aria-expanded="false">related</a>&nbsp;
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionGoTo13">
<a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-category/by/category/13">Category list</a>
<a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-post/by/category/13">Post list</a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Please help :)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a partial solution, you should use bootstrap navigation classes it should work fine. All you need separate both with `<div>` or use `<ul><li>` approach for creating your navigation:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
     <div>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Actions" role="button" id="dropdownActionMenu13" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">actions</a>&nbsp;
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionMenu13">
            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-category/action/13/hello_world">Hello World</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Related" role="button" id="dropdownActionGoTo14" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">related</a>&nbsp;
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownActionGoTo14">
            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-category/by/category/13">Category list</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="scaffold-post/by/category/13">Post list</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Further you can checkout how can place Navbar perfectly here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/